# Implode array using two array_column

Tags: php

I have a result from a query like this : (IN PHP, I assigned to $arr_permasalahan)

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| total_detail | nama_detail         |
+--------------+---------------------+
|            2 | Create Email Baru   |
|            1 | Create Login Novell |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

Now I want to implode them, like this :

```
Create Email Baru  : 2 pcs,
Create Login Novel : 1 pcs
```

So, I decided it to use array_column like this :

```
 $output =  implode("\n", array_column($arr_permasalahan, 'nama_detail'));
```

I just get

```
"Create Email Baru\nCreate Login Novell"
```

Please advise.

Comment: You can do it in the query only - `CONCAT(nama_detail, ' : ', total_detail, ' pcs')` and then print it as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use like this, it may help..! I think there is not need to use implode in this

```
     $line = "";
     foreach($arr_permasalahan as $line)
     echo "".$line[' nama_detail']." : ".$line['total_detail']." pcs";
```

Comment: I have tried this way, it success, but too oldiest style.

Comment: There is no benefit in prepending an empty string to the other data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
foreach($arr_permasalahan as $permasalahan)    
{
      echo $permasalahan['nama_detail']." : ".$permasalahan['total_detail']." pcs"."<br>";     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$elemet=implode("<br>",array_map(function($x){
    return $x['nama_detail'].":".$x['total_detail']." pcs";
},$arr_permasalahan));
echo $elemet;
```

**NOTE:** what @Sougata Bose suggested in comment will be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can impload array values using [impload()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Below mrentioned code will be full fill your requirement

```
$arr = array(1 => array('total_detail' => 2, 'nama_detail' => 'Create Email Baru'), 2 => array('total_detail' => 1, 'nama_detail' => 'Create Login Novell'));

  foreach ($arr as $i => $v) {
    $ss['nama_detail'] = $v['nama_detail'];
    $ss['total_detail'] = $v['total_detail'].' pcs';
    echo implode("':'",$ss)."' pcs<br>";
  }
```

Actually your result array is multi level array (2d-array) and impload() works for single level array so you must need to put a foreach loop.
See your required [result here](https://eval.in/728181)